# Is it safe to still use Java 6 and Eclipse Indigo for this application?

Tags: java, eclipse, security

We have an optimizer software written using Java and Optimj (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OptimJ), a tool that is tied to Eclipse.

However, Optimj is no longer mantained and we are stuck in using Eclipse Indigo (last version supported) for  this reason. Also, that means we cannot use newer versions of Java for our application because they won't work with Eclipse Indigo.

Our software is a standalone java program, totally developed by our team and runs in our servers, so we control 100% of the environment.

The only outside connection to the software (via modbus/TCP) is done by means of VPN with the company's other sites, so they can have access to the results. Our application is not directly exposed to the WWW.

In that situation, sticking to Eclipse Indigo and Java 6 poses any kind of security threat for us, so that a considerable investment in porting our optimization problem to another (considerably different) tool is justified?

Comment: So, you are asking if staying with Java 6 could pose a security threat?

Comment: Exactly! Also asked about Eclipse Indigo, too.

Comment: While you may not be able to use Java 7+ language constructs, you should be able to run the software on newer Java runtimes. And that's where the security bugs are.

Comment: Alright! I didn't realize I could build the application using the older environment (Java6+Indigo) and run it with the latest runtime environment. In that case, while I might have problems mantaining the code, security won't be a concern. Is that right?

Comment: Can you move the answer from the comments into an actual answer?

Comment: @zapl you could post your comment as an answer and I'll mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you may not be able to use Java 7+ language constructs, you should be able to run the software on newer Java runtimes. And that's where the security bugs are. *

> – zapl Dec 22 '16 at 15:29

*
**(I'm posting this on behalf of the legendary:  "zapl" a hero without a cape)**